# Converting fractional number from one base to another base

Tags: java

I am doing a task. I shoud convert fractional number in one base to another base. sourceBase = 35; sourceNum = af.xy;
newBase = 17;
I am getting 148.2062a. But correct answer should be 148.g88a8. I don;t know what to do.

```
        String fraction = "";
        String[] frac = sourceNumber.split("\\.");
        int val = Integer.parseInt(frac[0], sourceRadix);
        fraction += val + ".";
        result.append(Integer.toString(val, targetRadix)).append(".");
        val = Integer.parseInt(frac[1], sourceRadix);
        fraction += val;
        double dVal = Double.parseDouble(fraction);
        int decVal = (int) dVal;
        result.append(convertTo(dVal - decVal, targetRadix));
```

here is my convertTo() method.

```
public static String convertTo(double num, int rad) {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(num);
        double val = num * rad;
        System.out.println(val);
        int dec = (int) val;
        System.out.println(dec);
        result.append(Integer.toString(dec, rad));
        num = val - dec;
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that conversion of fraction part in _sourceRadix_ using `Integer.parseInt(num, radix)` is not correct: for a simple example of binary `1.11` to decimal, fractional part `.11` becomes 3 instead of `(1/2 + 1/4)*100=75`